# How to pass dependencies between controllers ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hello i have the following situation : I have 2 controllers A and B.I want to send from A to B an object ..use some actions of B and then return back to A.
On the other hand i want to access B directly too.

My data flow so far is the following:

```
Controller A ->Action-> View->Actionlink(object,Controller B)
```

The problem is with controller B.Since i can access it in two ways (with dependency from A or not) so far i would pass the dependency from ->Action->View->Action..etc->back to Controller A to not lose it as i illustrated below:

```
Controller B
{
Action1(Dependency c?)
{Viewbag.dependency=c??0;...} -> View(....ajax(depedency,Action2)
Action2(Dependency c?)
{} -> View.depedency=c??0...} -> View(ajax(dependency,Action3)
.....
ActionN(Dependency c?)
{
ReturnRedirect("action1",ControllerA)
}
```

As you can see i would just keep passing the dependency from action to view if not null until i make full circle (i return to A).Do i really need to do all this grunt work?

Also if the situation gets more complex lets say:

```
ControllerA->{DependencyA}->ControllerB->{DependencyA,DependencyB}->ControllerC
  ^                            ^                                     ^
  |                            |                                     | 
        <----------------               
                                           <----------------
```

I could access any of the three controllers separately but i could go from A to B with a dependency and close circle or continue from B to C and close circle.What would be a good approach?

Comment: Why not using TempData? http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: I'm very confused by the this scenario.  Controller actions are there own urls in the form of /controller/action.  also your controllers are created and destroyed every request/response cycle.  Are you saying the Controller A is creating data that then can be used later in other controller actions?  Then this  can be achieved with any number of techniques: TempData, Session, Cookie,...

Comment: You really shouldn't be passing back and forth between controllers and especially not via Viewbag.  If two different controllers need to do the same thing (as part of their processing) then you need to extrapolate to a service layer and have the controller actions call that common method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using NewtonSoft library for passing to another controller :

```
tempData[key]=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
```

I used the following extension methods:

```
public static class TempDataExt
    {
        public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData,string key,T value)
        {
            tempData[key]=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
        public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
        {
        object o;
        tempData.TryGetValue(key, out o);
        return o == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
        }
    }
```

For getting the tempdata object i am using:

```
    ViewData["tlocations"]=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TempData.Get<IEnumerable<long>>("tlocations"));
TempData.Keep();
```